# Can the joins table created by a has_many :through relation also have a has_many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relation, activerecord-relation

The model created by the has_many through relation would look like this:

```
class MerchantOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :products
end
```

But I am not sure if this is possible. Any reason why this wouldn't work?

Comment: There's no reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: What is not working? Show us the code you tried which failed

Comment: It hasn't failed. I am just getting used to using join tables and wasn't sure if their function could be extended beyond simply joining two models. But it sounds like this is perfectly acceptable.